# Permission denied while using mkdir on a windows server

Tags: php, windows

the problem is, im using a leased windows server, and im trying to create a directory using php function mkdir, whichever path i try gives the same result.

im using absolute something like this.

```
mkdir('D:\Hosting\3105674\html\lepsiprisma\hola',0777);
```

this returns

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in D:\Hosting\3105674\html\lepsiprisma\prueba.php  on line 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user that the webserver runs as, likely has no permissions to write in any of the directories under the web site (or server) root. You'd have to grant the right permissions to that user.